# Filemanager + Tinymce en Laravel

Tags: laravel

Buenas estoy intentando integrar `Filemanager + tinymce`. Para el tinymce sin ningún problema para que funcione pero el Filemanger no consigo que me reconozca la ruta. Teniendo en cuenta que soy bastante novato con Laravel es posible que se me este pasando algo.

He seguido este tuturial [introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://github.com/UniSharp/laravel-filemanager/tree/v1)

Bien he seguido estos pasos:

**Paquete de instalación**

```
composer require unisharp/laravel-filemanager
```

Como tengo la versión de Laravel 5.8.38 he tenido que saltarme dos pasos.

**Publico la configuración y los paquetes**

```
 php artisan vendor:publish --tag=lfm_config
 php artisan vendor:publish --tag=lfm_public
```

**Luego he añadido eso en web.php**

```
Route :: get ( '/ laravel-filemanager' , '\ UniSharp \ LaravelFilemanager \ controllers \ LfmController @ show' );
Route :: post ( '/ laravel-filemanager / upload' , '\ UniSharp \ LaravelFilemanager \ controllers \ UploadController @ upload' );
```

Pero me devuelve error 404 al entrar a través de tinymce para subir imagen.

**El JavaScript**

```
 var editor_config = {
        path_absolute : "/",
        selector: "textarea.my-editor",
        plugins: [
          "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
          "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
          "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
          "emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern"
        ],
        toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image media",
        relative_urls: false,
        file_browser_callback : function(field_name, url, type, win) {
          var x = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientWidth;
          var y = window.innerHeight|| document.documentElement.clientHeight|| document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientHeight;

          var cmsURL = editor_config.path_absolute + 'laravel-filemanager?field_name=' + field_name;
          if (type == 'image') {
            cmsURL = cmsURL + "&type=Images";
          } else {
            cmsURL = cmsURL + "&type=Files";
          }

          tinyMCE.activeEditor.windowManager.open({
            file : cmsURL,
            title : 'Filemanager',
            width : x * 0.8,
            height : y * 0.8,
            resizable : "yes",
            close_previous : "no"
          });
        }
      };

      tinymce.init(editor_config);
```

Ahí que decir que mi archivo `web.php` lo tengo con `middleware` ya que todo es través de estar registrado.

Answer (score 0):

He solucionado el error 404 de este modo:

```
var cmsURL = editor_config.path_absolute + 'adminJosep/public/laravel-filemanager?field_name=' + field_name;
```

Poniendo la URL correcta. 
Pero tengo una duda si subo ficheros desde el `tinymce` me los pone en `public/photos/archivos`

Pero si entro directamente a `laravel-filemanager` no me carga los que cargue desde el tinymce y estos me los guarda en una carpeta llamada `public/files/archivos..`